# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in AWS Gateway call from local vue js

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, cors, aws-api-gateway

i am using AWS API Gateway direct integrated to s3 to store any data to s3 .
i have enabled the CORS in S3 and api gateway , if i calling from postman or curl command its working fine and i can see i am getting response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *.

But when i am calling from vue js local machine alwys getting CORS error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://******/tests3/tryfinal44.txt' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

1 CORS Enabled in s3

```
 [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]
```

2 Curl operation working fine
curl -X PUT ****/onemore1221.txt  -d "testing the api" -i

3 Vue js calling code  -

```
 const article =  "Vue POST Request Example" ;
             const headers = {
                "Content-Type":'text/plain'
            };
            axios.put("**/tests3/tryfinal44.txt", article, { headers })
                .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                     })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.error("There was an error!", error);
                    });
```

4 API setting
[image]
i tried with ajax ,same issue with ajax call also .
Any suggestion will be help full .

Thanks
Dilip

Comment: Try removing  your content type header from your request

Comment: is your server side configured to correctly handle CORS ***preflight*** requests, since that's the request that is failing - P.S. nuff all to do with vue.js - this would fail regardless of what front end is in use

Comment: @Bravo  - according to me server side all is setup , i enabled CORS in S3 , i also enabled CORS  to API Gateway Resource . also curl operation response Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  its returning . there is any specific setting i need check ?

Comment: Sure, but did you do it right? seems like ***preflight*** requests are failing - you know what a perflight request is? You must, since according to you it's all setup, sorry to doubt you

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i already checked this no luck .

Comment: @Bravo sorry if i offended u , what i mean , yes i have setup CORS , if am not wrong Preflight is handshaking which called before actual api using option method . and give required header in response , please correct me if my understanding is wrong . i used below url to Enable  CORS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: you didn't offend me @Dilip . check the preflight in the browser. what is sent in the preflight? what is received in the preflight? perhaps if you know what is happening in the preflight you'll be able to debug why the preflight isn't working since the CORS setup is correct

Comment: Thanks @Bravo preflight giving 500 error , without any  response header  . x-amzn-errortype: InternalServerErrorException . i looking to check what configuration i did wrong , if u have suggestion , please let me know .

Comment: 500 error is an internal server error - so - check your server code

Comment: @Bravo i have look cloud watch its write error Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request . can u suggest something on this ?

Comment: no, because that sentence makes absolutely zero sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi we able to solve this issue , after discussing with aws support , as problem was not with cors.
actual problem was with preflight request was giving 500 .with this error

```
error Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request
```

we figure out Binary media in api setting */* was causing the problem in my case , i have changed to image/png and its started working .
Thanks for all help.